# Etymologie des mundartlichen alemanischen Worts „mol“

Tags: etymology, dialect, alemannic

In Vorarlberg und vielleicht auch in manchen anderen alemanischen Mundarten verwendet man das Wort *mol* wenn man in Deutschland *doch* und in übrigem Österreich *freilich* sagen würde.

Woher kommt das komische Wort, und hab ich dessen Verwendung richtig verstanden?

Comment: Kannst du ein Satzbeispiel mit Zusammenhang nennen? So ganz ohne Beispiel ist man da ein bißchen verloren.

Comment: @tofro es wäre mir sehr schwierig einen Satz in Alemanisch zu verfassen!... aber ein Versuch könnte etwa so aussehen: Vater:-Du hascht di erdäpfli nit uffigessen.  Sohn:- Mol, hab i! Isch no nur das Fleischli da!

Comment: Das lässt sehr stark auf eine Herkunft von *wohl* schließen - andere alemanische Dialekte würden das sehr ähnlich ausdrücken, allerdings mit "wohl ha[b|n] i"

Comment: Das *Idiotikon* verweist von **mol** auf **wohl**, und Grimm weiss zu **wohl**: *findet sich ... als partikel der beteuerung, vermutung, einschränkung, der verstärkung, des gegensatzes oder vergleiches* (auch wenn man dazu ziemlich suchen muss, der Eintrag ist riesig). Und zur Ethymologie: **wohl**, *gemeingermanisches adv. zu gut*

Comment: @tofro das wäre eine Antwort, denke ich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die übliche Schreibung ist *mol*, die Bedeutungen sind (a) "ja", (b) "nein" und (c) "doch". *Mol* ist eine Variante zu *wol*. Auch eine Reduplikation ist üblich: *mo(l)mol*. Zur Etymologie konnte ich nichts finden.

Quelle:

- https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id15.htm#!page/151349/mode/1up, dort in der rechten Spalte unter "**B.** Interj. *wol*"

Quellen zu "doch":

- https://www.pauker.at/pauker/DE_DE/SC/wb/?x=mol
- http://www.dialektwoerter.ch/ch/m.html
- http://www.schwiiz.eu/schweiz_deutsch_woerterbuch_k-m.php (s. molmoll)

Comment: Danke, hab die Schreibweise in der Frage korrigiert.